# Session handling in Flask API

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, session, flask

I am trying to create an API which will keep on generating questions using the Executable I created from the text that I give as an input using the API. Here is the Flask API code:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, make_response, request 
import flask
from shelljob import proc
import os
import subprocess
import json
import string
import unicodedata  
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/api/v22/QT/', methods=['GET'])

def people_api():
    text = request.args.get('text')

    text = unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', text).encode('ascii','ignore')

    text = text.decode('utf-8')
    text = text.replace('"','')

    Answer = subprocess.check_output(['QT', repr(text)])
    if text is None:
           make_response(jsonify({'error': 'Missing text parameter'}), 400)
    return flask.Response(Answer, mimetype= 'application/json' )
app.run('0.0.0.0',port=2000, threaded = True)
```

I have tested it and this is working fine. But I have noticed that the API is not able to maintain the session and results in the incorrect output. When I hit the API with different browsers at a time by changing the IP, I get same output for all the request. I could not understand, as I know Flask maintains session. But in my case I don't know why the session is not being maintained. I guess, I have missed something.

Kindly suggest what I need to do to maintain the session of the requests that I fire through my API.

Comment: What is session for you? :)

Comment: @Nabin Thank you for your queries. Look the session what I am considering is that the response should be delivered to the proper request. Say If we both are hitting the API with different text, so we should get the different outputs. But what in my case is: we both get the response of your request. Not mine but yours or anyone else, who so ever is hitting the API with different different text. Hence, I want to deliver the proper responses to the proper requests. Hope this clarifies your point.

Comment: What are the urls you are hitting? Please mention with value of text

Comment: I am having a local URL and the code I have mentioned is above: something like this: `localhost:2000//api/v22/QT/?text=Sometext from anywhere` and the output is the question generated using the text. The files are too huge as I have worked on training my model on the LDC dataset. Those are in TBs. So that trained model for this complete process is extremely huge.